# Error al ejecutar función en promesa

Tags: javascript, asynctask

En este código creo una función la cual ejecutará cualquier función pasado n segundos, he intento hacerlo con promesas y a su vez de forma recursiva.

```
El parámetro action, es la función a ejecutar,

seconds es los segundos que tardará en ejecutarse,

times es las veces que se ejecutará la funcion,
```

`c es un parámetro por defecto, que adquiere el valor de times`

**Y que sive de *variable de control* de la función ya que para repetir la funcion un numero de veces determinado, necesito saber cuantas veces llevo ejecutandola, entonces si `c > 0` , se ejecutara denuevo la función y cada vez que VUELVO a ejecutar la función le vuelvo a pasar los parámetros iniciales, pero con `times-1`, de esta forma `"c"` será menor y cuando llege a `cero`, terminará de ejecutarse.**

```js
function wait(action,seconds,times,c = times){
  if(c > 0) {
  return new Promise(done => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      done();
    },seconds);
  })
  .then(()=>{
    action(); 
  });
    
  } 
  else {
    wait(action,seconds,times-1)
  }
  
}



wait(()=>{
console.log("2 seconds..");
},2000,4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es llamar a una función secuencialmente cada `x`
segundos, `n` veces.

Para mí lo más fácil, utilizando solo promesas es lo siguiente, (no hay necesidad de recursividad):

```js
function handler(action, seconds){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, seconds);
  }).then(()=> Promise.resolve(action()));
}

function wait(action,seconds,times){
  return Array
    .from({ length : times })
    .reduce((promise, x) => 
      promise.then( ()=> handler(action, seconds) )
                        , Promise.resolve(null));
}



wait(()=>{
console.log("2 seconds..")
},2000,4).then( ()=> console.log('8 seconds'));;
```

Otra posible solución, utilizando `async/await`:

```js
function handler(action, seconds){
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(res, seconds);
  }).then( ()=> Promise.resolve(action()));
}

async function wait(action, seconds, times){
  let ts = times;
  while(ts--){
     await handler(action, seconds);
  }
  console.log(times*(seconds/1000) + ' seconds');
}


const handlerFn = () => console.log('2 seconds');
wait(handlerFn, 2000, 4);
```